# How to infer type to a generic type to a static method in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

**I'm trying to infer a generic type to the argument in a static method of a class**

Where is any type I would like to infer the generic type

This the props is type any
[image: This has props type any]

This the props is type Props
[image: This has props type Props]

```
interface Result<T> {
    data: T
}

class Base<G> {
    constructor(protected props: G){}

    // How to infer type G from generic to props instead any ???
    public static create(props: any /**G */): Result<Base<any>> {
        return { data: new Base(props) };
    }
}


// Props type
interface Props { key: string };


class Concrete1 extends Base<Props> {
    constructor(props: Props){
        super(props)
    }
}

// here the args is type any (I want to infer type Props)
const result = Concrete1.create({ key: "I am any" });

console.log(result.data);



// But on overrite static method it works. infer type
class Concrete2 extends Base<Props> {
    constructor(props: Props){
        super(props)
    }

    public static create(props: Props): Result<Concrete2> {
        return { data: new Concrete2(props) };
    }
}

// here the args has defined types
const result2 = Concrete2.create({ key: "I am Props type" });

console.log(result2.data);
```

Link to playground example: [Link Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoQM4FcA2YA8AKgHzIDeAUAJAAmcYcAXMoRQL4UUI5wYbIAhXhHwBxUpSoIA9iAxgoWBGGlQAFAAco0yMog1kW6RozNRASjIdqAehvIAEtIDuyFclAxobgJ4aUosgw2gC2yADmECDQwAhu0obaJh5ykHAGcCA+yAD8edQaWABGOLHI8vRlCFAQ9BCaSabImdk2AFRtgW025szo2Hj4QhgiLcQS1FQ1YFhQIOTIdAzM0a7D9UYm5shsANzUHNYUdsgACo2+-hSgkLCIKOfG-GTIANYQPszyUKDhO-ucbi8fgAYVk1QgkAAjMgIAAPSAgGj8db4R4mCZSWTfJQqdSbJrojCWSbYfz4xrmA7sTgnAAW0BQYAZzSg4X4wH4YD8KBayDUAElkM5MmB4ikvFBLg9KVxsWKagMxQBeZBgkAQ6EAOghdTUL3en2QACIhXAwi1jTtzACZHJpDgIFqcNJwmpFbgwFqlnAbZxafYBFgxbJkNIAG7QH6QcoMMBlEKQunSAzAMXOVSvDBaiXeblXIF8NXg6YQABMsIRUWRgmEaMamLtOOUqgaT2YRJJVCoZOgba21IKxVKcQq8biusg-cJlL6mE9+HVmvLmKmkNm8xePpWEFcS9LZen2z21Os9MZbhZcDZ-DpvEWEBgoH00owctSyA9eArqv3kPLOo1HqBofMwprNGERLSlabB+u+GAOk6Lpul+YBlt69C+gCQA)

Comment: The type inference is not perfect in typescript. Sometimes, it's possible, but typescript compiler/trampiler is not able to do that.

Comment: Generic class type parameters are inaccessible to static methods; it's essentially a [category error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_mistake) to try to do what you're doing.  Still, you could get similar behavior making the static method generic with a `this` parameter, like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w8EapN) shows.  Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer explaining what's going on; if not, what am I missing?